# Use Microsoft Graph to query user groups in ASP Net Core 2.1

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-ad-msal

It is possible to use Microsoft Graph in an old ASP Net Core 2.1 application?

My application is using OpenID Connect to authenticate users but I need to query Microsoft Graph to get the users groups. ( Previously this was done using Azure AD Graph )

Can someone point me to some old examples of code that are working with 2.1 framework. Most of the examples I found are with new framework versions.

```
// Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect, Version=2.1.2.0

          .AddOpenIdConnect(option =>
          {
              option.ClientId = ClientId;
              option.ClientSecret = ClientSecret;
              option.Authority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{Tenant}";
              option.Resource = "https://graph.microsoft.net";
              option.SignedOutRedirectUri = SignedOutRedirectUri;
              option.CorrelationCookie.Name = "cookie name";
              option.NonceCookie.Name = "nonce name";
              option.NonceCookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;                
              option.CorrelationCookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
              ....
          }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version of the [Microsoft.Graph](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph) package is .NET Standard 2.0 and will work with .NET Core 2.1.

And this [Microsoft Graph Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/dotnet?tabs=aad) will walk you through the very basics.

There is quite a bit to cover depending on what you are using MS Graph for, but I did find a small group of samples that may be useful.

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/2-WebApp-graph-user

> Note: I highly encourage you to update to the latest Long Term Support (LTS) version of .NET.  .NET Core 2.1 has been End-of-Lifecycle (EOL) since Aug, 2021.

### Update

I sanitized a working example I had and produced a small sample application here that is able to retrieve user groups.

Here is the [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/EntityAdam/GraphClientDemo)

The graph permissions assigned to the App Registration are as follows:

Delegated permissions:

- Group.Read.All
- GroupMember.Read.All
- offline_access
- openid
- profile
- User.Read
- User.Read.All
- User.ReadBasic.All

Comment: Thank you Adam! Initially I used this [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/aspnetcore2-2-signInAndCallGraph) by searching in history of the main branch. I didn't know about Microsoft.Graph package.